# Binary operator overloading in C++ with differing data types

Tags: c++, templates, comparison, operator-overloading, avl-tree

I'm working on implementing an AVL tree in C++. To keep things concise (and for practice), I'm trying to overload the comparison operators for the nodes of the tree.

Here's how I'd like the `find` function of the tree to look:

```
node* find(int key)
{
    node* currentNode = root;

    while (currentNode)
    {
        if (key < *currentNode)
        {
            currentNode = currentNode.getLeftChild();
        }
        else if (key > *currentNode)
        {
            currentNode = currentNode.getRightChild();
        }
        else
        {
            return currentNode;
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

In this instance, I could just overload the operator to compare `int` to `node` like so:

```
bool operator<(const int& lhs, const node& rhs)    // friend of node
{
    return lhs < rhs.key;
}
```

But this only seems to work with `int < node` not with `node < int`. Do I need to define a separate function for `node < int`?

I'd also like to template this function so that I can compare anything (that itself has comparison operators) to `node`s:

```
template<typename T> bool operator<(const T& lhs, const node& rhs)    // friend of node
{
    return lhs < rhs.key;
}
```

Again, this works for `T < node` but not for `node < T`. Do I need to define a function for `node < T` as well as the above function?

## TL;DR

If I overload an operator as `bool operator<(const foo& lhs, const bar& rhs)`, do I also need to define `bool operator<(const bar& lhs, const foo& rhs)` so that the operands can be either way around? Is this also the case with template functions like `template<typename T> bool operator<(const foo& lhs, const T& rhs)`?

Apologies if I've answered my own question here but the only resources I can find on operator overloading only show examples using the same type for both parameters. I'd just like to be sure I'm doing this right, and hopefully this post will come up the next time someone searches for this problem.

Comment: If you want to compare interchangably those types, maybe it makes sense to define a conversion operator between them?

Comment: Good idea! I'd never have thought of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets look at you function and the naming you are using

```
bool operator<(const int& lhs, const node& rhs)
```

So the `int` is called `lhs` and the `node` is `rhs`.  Thes names match what side of the operator the types lie.  `lhs` is **l**eft **h**and **s**ide and `rhs` is **r**ight **h**and **s**ide.  So

```
bool operator<(const int& lhs, const node& rhs)
```

Will only work when you have

```
int < node
```

If you want to hadle

```
node < int
```

Then you would need another function where the `node` is the `lhs` and the `int` is the `rhs`

```
bool operator<(const node& lhs, const int& rhs)
```

Now you can template this like

```
template<typename T> bool operator<(const T& lhs, const node& rhs)    // friend of node
{
    return lhs < rhs.key;
}

template<typename T> bool operator<(const node& lhs, const T& rhs)    // friend of node
{
    return lhs.key < rhs;
}
```

And this will give you `operator <` for all types that `T < node::key` is defined where `T` and `node` appear on either side of `<`.

Comment: I tried this and got this compiler error:

`*snip*.cpp(74): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'bool operator <(const node &,const T &)'
  *snip*.cpp(74): note: With the following template arguments:
  *snip*.cpp(74): note: 'T=node'
*snip*.cpp(74): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'bool operator <(const T &,const node &)'
  *snip*.cpp(74): note: With the following template arguments:
  *snip*.cpp(74): note: 'T=int'
*snip*.cpp(74): error C2677: binary '<': no global operator found which takes type 'node' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Answer (score 1):

its considered good practice. Many library developers have done it the same way. boost is one such example, If you define both operations separately.

```
bool operator < (const foo& lhs, const bar& rhs);
bool operator < (const bar& lhs, const foo& rhs);
```

To be specific to your problem, if you wish to have just one template comparison function, you can do it following way:

```
template<typename T>
bool less(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    return lhs < rhs;
}

class node
{
private:
    int nodeValue;

public:
    explicit node(int i):nodeValue(i){}
```

> Below conversion function defined for comparison with int, same can be
>   defined for char or a user defined data type

```
    operator int()const
    {
        return nodeValue;
    }
};

void test()
{
    node tmp(75);

    std::cout<<"less<int>(tmp, 10):"<<less<int>(tmp, 10)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"less<int>(10, tmp):"<<less<int>(10, tmp)<<std::endl;
}
```

Building onto this, you can use this approach for two different user defined date types provided they have conversion functions defined to some data type which has operator **<** defined.